# how can I find out font size used by best fit in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

This question is related to http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption_bestfit .
Suppose I am writing a single digit number using font "Comic-Sans-MS-Bold" in 40x40 area so that it occupies maximum space and does not overflow.
Say imagemagick chose font size 'x' .
If I were to write a two digit number using font "Comic-Sans-MS-Bold" in 40x40 area.
Then imagemagick would choose some other font size 'y' .
Is there a debug option or some other method using which I can find out what font size was decided for writing a particular text in specified area .
Actually, I need that font size so that I can specify it explicitly in my tkinter script when I create similiar image using draw text over canvas. 
Thanks.
BTW , imagemagick forum is locked .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a better way to do that in ImageMagick.

```
convert -size 200x50 -background white -font candice caption:"This Is Some Text" -format "%[caption:pointsize]\n" info:
```

23

Comment: [cmd]magick  -size 40x40 -background white -font "Comic-Sans-MS-Bold" caption:"1" -format "%[caption:pointsize]\n" info:[/cmd] shows that 1 of pointsize 26 fits in 40x40 block. Your answer is better because it does not create image and output is only required information . Thanks .

Answer (score 3):

You can find the font size in **ImageMagick** caption: using **-debug annotate** as follows. You will get a long list showing all the iterations of font size tried. The last one is what you want.

```
convert -debug annotate -size 200x50 -background white -font candice caption:"This Is Some Text" result.jpg
```

```
2020-06-01T19:02:46+00:00 0:00.044 0.040u 6.9.11 Annotate convert[53791]: annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1486/Annotate
  Font /Library/Fonts/Candice.ttf; font-encoding none; text-encoding none; pointsize 12
2020-06-01T19:02:46+00:00 0:00.045 0.040u 6.9.11 Annotate convert[53791]: annotate.c/GetTypeMetrics/862/Annotate
  Metrics: text: T; width: 12.5312; height: 15; ascent: 10; descent: -4; max advance: 15; bounds: 0.484375,-1  12.5312,9; origin: 12.5312,0; pixels per em: 12,12; underline position: -1.26; underline thickness: 0.6
2020-06-01T19:02:46+00:00 0:00.045 0.040u 6.9.11 Annotate convert[53791]: annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1486/Annotate
  Font /Library/Fonts/Candice.ttf; font-encoding none; text-encoding none; pointsize 12
2020-06-01T19:02:46+00:00 0:00.046 0.040u 6.9.11 Annotate convert[53791]: annotate.c/GetTypeMetrics/862/Annotate
  Metrics: text: Th; width: 16.3438; height: 15; ascent: 10; descent: -4; max advance: 15; bounds: 0.125,-0.328125  6.34375,8; origin: 16.3438,0; pixels per em: 12,12; underline position: -1.26; underline thickness: 0.6
2020-06-01T19:02:46+00:00 0:00.046 0.040u 6.9.11 Annotate convert[53791]: annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1486/Annotate
  Font /Library/Fonts/Candice.ttf; font-encoding none; text-encoding none; pointsize 12
2020-06-01T19:02:46+00:00 0:00.046 0.040u 6.9.11 Annotate convert[53791]: annotate.c/GetTypeMetrics/862/Annotate

.
.
.
  Metrics: text: This Is Some Text; width: 193.703; height: 28; ascent: 19; descent: -7; max advance: 29; bounds: 0.734375,-2.09375  7.70312,11.8906; origin: 193.703,0; pixels per em: 23,23; underline position: -2.415; underline thickness: 1.15
2020-06-01T19:02:46+00:00 0:00.194 0.180u 6.9.11 Annotate convert[53791]: annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1486/Annotate
  Font /Library/Fonts/Candice.ttf; font-encoding none; text-encoding none; pointsize 23
```

**So the result is pointsize 23**

Comment: [cmd] magick -debug annotate -background white -fill black -font "Comic-Sans-MS-Bold" -size 40x40  caption:1 one-debug.png [/cmd] shows that 1 fits with pointsize 26 in 40x40 block . Your suggestion works . Thanks .

Comment: See the better and much simpler answer above that uses `-format "%[caption:pointsize]\n" info:`

Comment: fmw42, I think you are in imagemagick forum too . Why it got locked ?

Comment: The ImageMagick forum has moved to GIT for better maintainability. You can still read old posts on the old Discourse server, but not ask any new questions there. New questions should be asked at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions